# Where can I download older revision of Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-sdk-1.6

I'm in need of a download for revision 16, since they seem to have broken Processing compatibility. I can't find it on the SDK website, the only  thing I can come up with is googling the filename "installer_r16-windows.exe" but it doesn't seem to be hosted anywhere ligitimately, which I would prefer to avoid.

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume you actually mean the SDK Tools rather than the SDK (since that's only at API 15)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r16-windows.exe

or more generally

http://dl.google.com/android/installer_rXX-windows.exe

They aren't not listed, you just have to fix it in the URI !