# Where to download android tools for 4.2 (revision 17)

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'd like to develop for a 4.2 OS phone and right now I can only target 4.4 rev19.

I tried several google searches, but came up with nothing :( Maybe I'm calling it the wrong thing? Lookin for some help here.

Here are my troubleshooting efforts.

When I look on the dev site, this doesn't contain a download link: http://developer.android.com/tools/revisions/build-tools.html

I was hoping that my v19 would have prior versions in it, so I did the following (which proves it doesn't have them in it ;))

Right click the proj, > Android Tools > Add Support Library, but the option isn't in there.

From another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450008/where-can-i-download-older-revision-of-android-sdk), I did find a direct link to dl v17, but even after downloading, the "Target Framework" available for a new Android App Project is still 19 for me.. how to get that sucker updated?

Comment: you have to download 4.2 SDK in the android sdk manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load API level 17 from the SDK Manager if you don't have 17 installed. The link below will help you with this:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Comment: Thanks all! Very helpful info and helped me out

Answer (score 2):

To show you a visual of what dean and mihail are talking about, see the attached screen shot. To open the SDK manager, click the icon on the Android Studio task bar that appears next to the text "Android SDK Manager" in the screen shot:[image: sdk manager]